# Devise - do not use email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, passwords

I want Devise authentication to use login instead of email and skip email validations, but keep password validations. How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Everything is explained [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address), particularly how to get rid of email (see at the bottom).

Answer (score 4):

To change what model property devise uses for authentication, you are going to want to look at the "Configuration for any authentication mechanism" section in the devise.rb file. You will at least need to change

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]
```

to

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

and you probably want to change

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
```

to

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :login ]
```

You should also look at the link apneadiving provides as it explains how you can make these changes in just one model instead of changing it for all models(which is what changing devise.rb does).

To change the regex that devise uses for validating emails, you can change the config.email_regexp property to whatever you want - e.g. ".*" would let anyone use ANYTHING as a login, so I don't recommend that.

Comment: Care to explain any further? I did assume you had a login field defined in your User model already. You do have to make view changes as well like "text_field :login" instead of "email_field :email" in sessions/new.html.erb if you are using the default devise views.

Answer (score -1):

The right answer is here: http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2011/12/08/the-one-where-devise-validations-are-customized/